# Stop Gmail folders from showing up

Tags: gmail

So, I have quite a lot of  labels for mails in Gmail. Now I don't really need some labels but don't want to delete them either. So, I'm trying to hide/archive those labels so they don't clutter my Gmail. Now I did these setting>labels >

1. Show in label list> hide
2. Show in message list > hide
3. Show in IMAP > unchecked

   How do I stop them certain labels from showing up when I am moving mails?

Comment: Please note: Gmail uses labels, not folders. There's a difference.